# Create SAS dataset using Teradata "With" clause

Tags: sql, sas, dataset, teradata, with-statement

I am trying to create SAS dataset using Teradata SQL passthrough.

```
   Proc sql;
   connect to teradata(%login);
   create table Data as 
   select * from connection to teradata
   (
     with table as (
        select id, amount from
        TeradataTable
   ),
  select distinct id from Data
);
Quit;

 Error: Syntax error, expected something like a name or unicode delimited identifier between ',' and the 'select' keyword
```

Can someone let me know how to create a SAS dataset using Teradata With statement? Thanks

Comment: Remove the comma before the SELECT DISTINCT. Also I assume the name in the FROM clause is actually the name in the WITH and your anonymized example has a typo.

Comment: Thank you.. It works without comma. Yes.. it was a typo